# Is a room with only a shower the same as a normal bathroom?

Tags: halacha, shema, bathroom

In terms of the halachos in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim Siman 85 (which places is it ossur to say Krias Shema) would a small room with just a shower head have the same dinim as a room with a toilet or a room with just a bathtub?

Comment: I heard that a rabbi of this generation (I can't remember who) told his students to review their learning in the shower that wasn't attached to a room with a toilet

Comment: @ba While unclothed? And if not, what were they doing hanging out in the shower?

Comment: In a changing room, where people are only sometimes unclothed it would be ok to talk about Torah, but one should not say Bruchot or Hashem's name (eg. Shalom aleichem). It's not the same a toilet, where there could be excrement. However, modern toilets remove the waste entirely, and once the smell is gone it's arguably just a changing room.

Comment: @DoubleAA You're allowed to think Torah when naked, if I remember correctly

Comment: @ba Yes, you are correct. When naked you are allowed to think Torah, but not say it. But you are not allowed to even think it when excrement is present. Couples are recommended to think good thoughts (i.e. divrey torah) when alone together.

Answer (score 2):

Did you also see Siman 84? It talks about a Bathhouse, which is what a room with just a shower or tub is.

However, a modern bathroom, where everything is flushed away probably also has the din of a bathhouse.

Siman 85 applies where the waste is actually present.